# php - Stripe Usage Record class not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add usage records to my subscription. using the stripe create usage record endpoint (https://stripe.com/docs/api#usage_record_create).

running my function im getting an error returning saying `Class 'Stripe\UsageRecord' not found in file` I havent defined the namespace because I have beeen accessing it directly referencing stripe using `\Stripe\` which I brought in using `composer`. I've tried a `composer update` but that didnt seem to do the trick. I'm guessing it's missing the `UsageRecord.php` file from the `composer install` but I have no clue where to add a copy of the file to the stripe package

```
  public function stripeUsageRecord()
  {
    $authUser = auth()->user();
    $business = $authUser['business_id'];
    $user_amount = Transactions::select("user_id")
      ->where("business_id", "=", $business)
      ->groupBy("user_id")->count();
    $current_time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));

    \Stripe\UsageRecord::create(array(
      "quantity" => $user_amount,
      "timestamp" => $current_time,
      "subscription_item" => 'sub_DnAKVwNY2Sc4zf',
      "action" => 'set'
    ));
  }
```

Comment: If you're using composer, are you including the autoloader in your file? And are you declaring your intention to `use` the specified class?

Comment: Yes I was. My problem was the stripe package was literally missing the `UsageRecord.php`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seemed like I was missing a part of the stripe package.

I found a copy of `UsageRecord.php` online and created the file in path `vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\UsageRecord.php`

I then added the contents of the code that I found online and added them to the file and it worked. The contents are posted below:

```
<?php

namespace Stripe;

/**
* Class UsageRecord
*
* @package Stripe
*
* @property string $id
* @property string $object
* @property bool $livemode
* @property int $quantity
* @property string $subscription_item
* @property int $timestamp
*/
class UsageRecord extends ApiResource
{

const OBJECT_NAME = "usage_record";

/**
* @param array|null $params
* @param array|string|null $options
*
* @return \Stripe\ApiResource The created resource.
*/
public static function create($params = null, $options = null)
{
  self::_validateParams($params);
  if (!array_key_exists('subscription_item', $params)) {
      throw new Error\InvalidRequest("Missing subscription_item param in request", null);
  }
  $subscription_item = $params['subscription_item'];
  $url = "/v1/subscription_items/$subscription_item/usage_records";
  $request_params = $params;
  unset($request_params['subscription_item']);

  list($response, $opts) = static::_staticRequest('post', $url, $request_params, $options);
  $obj = \Stripe\Util\Util::convertToStripeObject($response->json, $opts);
  $obj->setLastResponse($response);
  return $obj;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using too old version of this library. `Stripe\UsageRecord` was [introduced](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/commit/67e8c4fbf6139f48416ac67ffb70471abddc85d6#diff-aa969dfb3e73c4de03f23d553214e83c) in version 6.6.0, so I suggest to update library to the last version:

```
composer require "stripe/stripe-php:^6.19"
```

You definitely should not modify content of `vendor` directory and copy&paste classes from different version of library.

Comment: I was using the "laravel/cashier":"~7.0" package as per the laravel 5.6 documentation

Comment: Should a composer update not have updated it aswell?

Comment: It should, but other constraints or requirements may block this. If you try to upgrade explicitly, you may get more info what is blocking this update.